# Is it possible for a command or function to end in command line mode?

Tags: command-line

It's possible to configure a mapping such that command line mode is active after the key press.

For example, with a mapping `:map H :help` , pressing `H` results in command line mode being entered with `:help`  as the current text.

The documentation for `:normal` says:

> A ":" command must be completed as well.  And you can't use "Q" or "gQ" to start Ex mode.

Therefore, it's not possible to execute `:normal :` and end up in command line mode.

Are there commands such that command line mode is active upon completion?

Can a Vimscript function be used where command line mode is active with some specified text, *after* running the function *directly* (i.e., via a `:call` entered in isolation, as opposed to being wrapped in a mapping that can result in command line mode)?

Comment: Certainly you can create a mapping (e.g. `nnoremap <leader>x :`) that leaves you on command line. Don't know if that helps you...  (oops...Luc's answer hadn't shown up for me before I hit send..oh well, I'll leave it since it's related)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`feedkeys()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#feedkeys%28%29) function for this purpose.

For example:

```
function! Edit()
    call feedkeys(':edit ', 'n')
endfunction
```

Then `:call Edit()` will enter the Ex command-line, enter `:edit`  into it and leave the cursor there for the user to complete and eventually execute the Ex command.

As [`:help feedkeys()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#feedkeys%28%29) explains:

> By default the string is added to the end of the typeahead buffer, [...]
> The function does not wait for processing of keys contained in `{string}`.

I also recommend that you take a close look at `:help feedkeys()` for the possible values of `{mode}`, I used `'n'` for no-remap in my example, but there are more mode flags that you might find interesting for your specific situation.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution: you'll need a mapping and have the mapping returns the value of a function that returns a sequence that will have us end in command mode.

Comment: Thanks for posting this workaround. However, my interest is in running the function directly, without a mapping. I've updated the question to make this more clear.

Comment: I've learned to distrust some solutions like `feedkeys()` -- there are too many side effects for my tastes. In the end, if I want to execute a function that may make me end up in command mode, this means that what calls the functions (typically a mapping somewhere) will receive the order to go into command mode, from the various function(s) called. There is a limitation: it won't work as  well with commands to end up in command mode from commands.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with Luc. `feedkeys()` should be avoided whenever possible.

Carefully using `:map-<expr>` (or even `:h abbreviations`, as you seem to "misuse" a command to compose another command, see `:h :cnoreabbrev`) works in 90+ percent of cases. But if you really want the user to input a line or two, you can always fake it with `:h input()` and `:h execute()`.